# Use of undeclared type 'ContactsTableViewCell'

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am working on to fetch phone contacts. But I got an error like  *use of undeclared type* `ContactsTableViewCell`. I tried `UITableViewCell` but it didn't work. What should I do ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell

    let data = dataArray![indexPath.row] as! Data;
    cell.lblName.text = data.name
    cell.imgContact.image = data.image
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you created a class for ContactsTableViewCell?

Comment: Somewhere in your module there must be a `class ContactsTableViewCell { ...}`. And `Data` is a reserved word in Swift 3. Do not use it as a custom struct / class.

Comment: copy and paste error?

Comment: Okay I created ContactsTableViewCell class but didn't inherit UITAbleViewCell before. Now I did and it fixed. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should make a class named `ContactsTableViewCell` which inherit `UITableViewCell` or if you already created it be sure you added this class to your targets.

Comment: Accepted answer with -2. :D

Comment: yes I want to give a plus to you so if anyone has a problem with that they have to find me :) okay thanks man @K. Michał

Comment: You can do it by clicking an triangle pointing upwards to the left of my answer.

Comment: I know I tried but it doesn't work. Just notification appear like '  thanks for the feedback ' :)

Comment: Ahh your reputation is too low for plusing it yet so ask more question and help others. I did plus your question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)